# Calling js function in external js file from within a script tag

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag, external-js

I have an HTML file with a script tag. In order to reuse the functions common to other pages, I have created an external JS file with some functions. Now, if I link the external JS file in the head and try to access the functions as attributes for HTML tag using onclick="functionname()", it works. But I want to call the functions in the external JS file within the script tag ( I need to pass parameters to the functions and I extract those values within the script tag), I am not able to do so. Is it even possible to call functions in the external file within the script tag? If yes, how can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to use the same function in a different HTML files?

Comment: Yes. So that I can reuse them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create js file. E.g. `index.js`
2. Add index.js file in your HTML files using `script` tag
3. Add `onClick="functionName()"` in your html

Make sure the function which you use must be present in the `index.js` file

Check Below Code

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function call() {
        showAlert()
    }
</script>

<button onclick="call()">Call External Function</button>
</body>
```

First load external js file like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

Add new script tag and add one another function to call external function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callExternalFun() {
    showAlert()
}
</script>
```

After that add `callExternalFun()` in your HTML

```
<button onclick="callExternalFun()">Call External Function</button>
```

External JS code `index.js` which contains `showAlert` function

```
function showAlert() {
  alert("External JS Function")
}
```

Comment: I want to call the function from within the script tag. There will be two places I will have js- one in the HTML file using script tag and the other is an external js file. I want to call the function in the external file from inside the script tag and not from the html element. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Updated answer please check

Answer (score 0):

In the external js file:

```
function myExternalFunction(param) {
    //some code
}
```

In the html file:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="<path to the external js file>"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         //here you can call your external function
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```